# Success Factors - updating custom Picklists

Tags: python, api, postman, sap-successfactors

Using Postman Version 7.34.0 (7.34.0)
Technically I am using Django / Python in my application, but I am testing using Postman, I will use the same payload while making a call to the Success Factors ATS.
The documentation for SuccessFactors: [link](https://help.sap.com/doc/74597e67f54d4f448252bad4c2b601c9/2005/en-US/SF_HCM_OData_API_REF_en.pdf)

I am trying to update a Candidate entity, in particular a **custom** `Picklist`, with **custom** `PicklistOptions` on that Candidate entity.
I was given a list of values for each Picklist, like this one:

```
Field ID: "myCustomPicklist" (used as name field in the payload)
Field label: Some Label (irrelevant - used for UI display)
Field Type: Picklist
```

And for each option of the Picklist:

```
...
PicklistOption value: <Str, "some_value"> (value string displayed in the UI)
PicklistOption external code: <Str, "picklistOption_external_code">
PicklistOption external ID: <Int, picklistOption_id >
...
```

I was able to update the `Picklist` field on the candidate using the `PicklistOption` external IDs, this way:
`POST: https://<subdomain>.successfactors.eu/odata/v2/upsert`
Payload:

```json
{
    "__metadata": {"uri": "Candidate(<candidate_id>)"},
    "firstName": "some_name",
    "lastName": "some_last_name",
    ...
    "myCustomPicklist": {
        "__metadata": {"uri": "PicklistOption('<picklistOption_id>')"},
        "optionValue":"<picklistOption_id>"
    }
}
```

Response:

```xml
...
<d:status>OK</d:status>
<d:editStatus>UPDATED</d:editStatus>
<d:message>Candidate has been updated successfully</d:message>
<d:index m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:index>
<d:httpCode m:type="Edm.Int32">204</d:httpCode>
...
```

**The problem:**
I understand that the `PicklistOption.external-id` is the ID from the DB, and that means that I would have to get a different ID to interact within different environments - that would force me to create a special map, and I wouldn't want that.
**My question:**
How can I use the `picklistOption_external_code` instead?
I am looking for the right syntax, as I was not able to find it in the documentation.
That would allow me to have a single map of fields, as the code (naming) will not change between environments, while the IDs will change.

Thank you!

**EDIT 1**
This works:

```json
"myCustomPicklist": {
    "__metadata": {"uri": "PicklistOption('<picklistOption_id>')"},
    "externalCode":"<picklistOption_external_code>"
}
```

But I cannot find the syntax for replacing the last occurrence of the `picklistOption_id` in the `metadata`

**EDIT 2**
This also works. Well, almost:

```json
"myCustomPicklist": {
    "__metadata": {"uri": "PicklistOption('<PicklistOption_value>')"},
    "externalCode":"<picklistOption_external_code>"
}
```

This seems to pass the validation:

```xml
<d:message>Candidate has been updated successfully</d:message>
```

The `PicklistOption_value` is a legitimate descriptor for the `PicklistOption` - but the UI in SuccessFactors seems to override the displayed content for the field with `null` value.
I verified that if I use a fake `PicklistOption_value` I see an error:

```xml
<d:message>Candidate upsert failed: myCustomPicklist invalid,  with the index 0</d:message>
```

Answer (score 0):

For any given SAP SuccessFactors entity (table), the way the picklist has to be used with either OptionID or externalCode is predefined by SAP in the product.

Use the OData Dictionary for the entity, and for the field's navigation data, check the Type column.  It will be either: PicklistOption or PickListValueV2.

See SAP KBA 2773713: https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2773713

As you noted, if using OptionID, then your solution must account for different number values in different SuccessFactors instances.